# Create Multi-Resize-Windows (like jsfiddle.net) with JQuery

Tags: jquery, resize

Is it possible to create the same window-resize like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrbW8/24/) with jQuery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're maybe looking for this plugin, [jQuery Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/).

[simple demo](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html)

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery Layout plugin from the accepted answer is no longer supported and has lot of issues with new jQuery updates. Check out the following plugin [Splitter Plugin](http://www.methvin.com/splitter/). Just in case if anyone else is stumbling around.

Comment: A 2008 solution to replace a 2010 solution?... :/

Comment: jquery layout is bad to use now